# Connection error to localhost database c#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, database-connection

Hi I'm trying to connect to a database using System.Data.SqlClient. I think I have everything correct, but for some reason Visual Studio gives out an error:

EDIT:
It turns out I was dumb and using System.Data.SqlClient when my database is MySql so I changed it to MySql.Data.MySqlClient and changed all the variables methods and everything. I also changed the port that It was using to 3306 cause it's the port I have set for mysql in xampp. Although I still get an error that says:

System.ArgumentException: „Connection option 'server' is duplicated.”

Now to answer some more questions, I don't know what is the name of the instance but I never set any so Idk if there is one or not(Sorry I'm not very advanced). I didn't add a password to the connection string cause the only user I have is root without any password. I think I seen some people used something like TrusedConnection=true or something but I don't know if it's the right thing to do here. My MySql version is 15.1. Here is the updated code:

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            string conn = "Initial Catalog=world.sql;user=root;Server=127.0.0.1,3306";

            MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(conn);
            MySqlDataReader myReader = null;
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM coutry";

            MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, myConnection);
           
                myConnection.Open();
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < myReader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(myReader[i].ToString());
                    }

                }
                myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and 1) add a tag for the type of SQL you're dealing with and 2) give us more information about your SQL instance (can you connect using a tool like SSMS? , what port is that instance listening on? what's the name of your sql instance etc) and 3) Explain why there isn't a password in your connection string

Comment: Do you know the difference between Sql Server and MySql? Sql Server uses port 1433 by default and the SqlClient library, while MySql uses port 3050 and MySql client library.

Comment: Excuse me, I meant port 3306 for MySql. Also, the highest current version of MySql is 8.0.26. There is no MySql 15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a connection string format like this: `Server=localhost;User=user_name;Database=db_name;Port=3306;Password=password;SSL Mode=None`
and apart from that, never use the root account. Just create an account that has a password.
If you apply these things to your code, the error should disappear.

Comment: You might need to change the port if it does not suit your situation.

Comment: I love you <3 <3

Comment: @shade999, can you accept the answer so that others can benefit?

Answer (score -1):

use This connection in C#

```
Data Source=yourIpAddress,yourPort;Initial Catalog=YourdatabaseName;User ID=sqlserverUsername;Password=sqlserverpassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient";
```

Comment: `Data Source=yourIpAddress,yourPort` is incorrect for MySQL. See https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/ or https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-8-0-connection-options.html.

Comment: I thought he were useing SQL Server , sorry